# How to speed up my script?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, performance, code-review

I am looking for the way to speed up my script. It is working fine, I mean, the final output is as required, but it is clunky and really slow. It is slow because of the double 'for..in..' loops, I know. So, how to make it smoother a bit?
   **What my script do:** - it is updating existing feature classes. I have two folders where all up-to-date shapefiles(shp) are stored. My script checks what shps are in each folder, and then is searching for the same named featureclasses (these are older versions) in 4 geodatabases. So shp has to go to the gdb that already contains featureclass with the same name. I hope it is simple enough.
Just to give you some idea, it takes over 1h to run this script, I have about 45 shapefiles (about 1gb), thats are copied over to 4 geodatabases. Is it any way to avoid these time consuming double 'for..in..'loops.
  My Script:

```
import time
import os
import arcpy
import gc
import sys
startTime = time.clock()

print "Start"

FCProducts = r"Y:\FCProducts"
GBProducts = r"Y:\GBProducts"
adminBdry = r"J:\Projects\Admin\DataBase1.gdb"
GnR = r"J:\Projects\Gnr\DataBase2.gdb"
Invenories = r"J:\Projects\Inventories\DataBase3.gdb"
NFE = r"J:\Projects\NFE\DataBase4.gdb"


arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
try:
   arcpy.env.workspace = FCProducts
   listFC = [0]
   listFC = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
   del arcpy.env.workspace

   for product in listFC:
       f2fOutput = product[:-4] + "_new"

       arcpy.env.workspace = GnR
       listGnrFC = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
       for gnrFC in listGnrFC:
          if gnrFC == product[:-4]:
              arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(product[:-4], GnR, f2fOutput)
              print product, " copied to ", GnR
              arcpy.Delete_management(gnrFC)
              arcpy.Rename_management(f2fOutput, product[:-4])

       del arcpy.env.workspace
       arcpy.env.workspace = adminBdry
       listAdBdryFC = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
       for AdBdry in listAdBdryFC:
           if AdBdry == product[:-4]:
               arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(product[:-4], adminBdry, f2fOutput)
               print product, " copied to ", adminBdry
               arcpy.Delete_management(AdBdry)
               arcpy.Rename_management(f2fOutput, product[:-4])

       del arcpy.env.workspace
       arcpy.env.workspace = Invenories
       listInventFC = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
       for invent in listInventFC:
           if invent == product[:-4]:
               arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(product[:-4], Invenories, f2fOutput)
               print product, " copied to ", Invenories
               arcpy.Delete_management(invent)
               arcpy.Rename_management(f2fOutput, product[:-4])

       del arcpy.env.workspace
       arcpy.env.workspace = NFE
       listNfeFC = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
       for nfe in listNfeFC:
           if nfe == product[:-4]:
               arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(product[:-4], NFE, f2fOutput)
               print product, " copied to ", NFE
               arcpy.Delete_management(nfe)
               arcpy.Rename_management(f2fOutput, product[:-4])

   del arcpy.env.workspace
   arcpy.env.workspace = GBProducts
   listFCgb = [0]
   listFCgb = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
   del arcpy.env.workspace

   for productGB in listFCgb:
       f2fOutputGB = productGB[:-4] + "_new"
       arcpy.env.workspace = Invenories
       listInventGB = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
       for InventGB in listInventGB:
          if InventGB == productGB[:-4]:
              arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion (productGB[:-4], Invenories, f2fOutputGB)
              print productGB, " copied to ", Invenories
              arcpy.Delete_management(InventGB)
              arcpy.Rename_management(f2fOutputGB, productGB[:-4])

       del arcpy.env.workspace
       arcpy.env.workspace = NFE
       listNfeGB = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
       for nfeGB in listNfeGB:
           if nfeGB == productGB[:-4]:
              arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion (productGB[:-4], NFE,f2fOutputGB)
              print productGB, " copied to ", NFE
              arcpy.Delete_management(nfeGB)
              arcpy.Rename_management(f2fOutputGB, productGB[:-4])


except Exception, e:
    # If an error occurred, print line number and error message
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print "Line %i" % tb.tb_lineno
    print e.message

finally:
    gc.collect()

    print "completed within:", time.clock() - startTime, "seconds", "\n"
```

Comment: If you use `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`, you don't need to delete and rename the new fc, just overwrite the existing one with Feature Class to Feature Class.

Comment: Also, if you can migrate to at least ArcGIS 10.1 SP1, you could use the `arcpy.da.walk` function to search your 4 geodatabases together, instead of using the same code for the 4 gdb separately.

Comment: it is there, just after all variables, and dont seems to work properly, without adding '_new' i am getting an error that output already exists.  Arc10.0 that is all I have access to, i am affraid.

Comment: Yes I've seen it, that's why I thought it was redundant. It's weird that it is ignored. Do you have any SP installed? 10.0 alone is not the less buggy version of ArcGIS to say the least.

Comment: SP5 (build 4400 )

Comment: This is probably a trivial improvement I don't believe you need all those "del arcpy.env.workspace" lines as you always set the workspace before you use the ListFeatureClasses() method. Removing those would simplify the code a bit.

Comment: Another thing is that you create a list of featureclasses (e.g.listNfeGB) then you cycle through this list until it matches productGB[:-4]. I'm guessing you test this as you may not have it in the currently searched geodatabase? In python you can ask if some exists in a list rather than step through until it is found. You would do something like "if productGB[:-4] in listNfeGB:" then blah blah blah.

Comment: @Hornbydd, I have been testing the 'exests' method you mentioned, but for some reason i have resigned from it, dont remember now why... but it is really worth to play with, thanks

Comment: List comprehension to filter out if the feature class names `== product[:-4]` will be faster than if statements in a loop. Additionally you are doing the same thing inside each loop. Why not define a function and map to the function with your iterable, see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

Comment: @JamesSLC,  Thanks for your comment, that may work. I am away for 2days but will definitely try the 'map' function...

Comment: I think you are asking for a [codereview.se] and there is a Stack Exchange site for that which has now accumulated 44 [geospatial questions](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geospatial).

Comment: @PolyGeo, Yes, main part of my question is related to code review, but I am totally open for alternative ways of solving my problem, pythonic or just arcpy... You are the boss here :) I can move my question to stack exchange, if you think it is more appropriate place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of the policy written some time ago at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317/code-review-for-a-specific-piece-of-code